# {} внутри объекта

Tags: javascript

Я не совсем понимаю, зачем в объекте делать еще один объект?

Это свойство объекта в объекте?

Я совсем запутался, объясните, если вам не тяжело.

```js
let meetup = {
  title: "Conference",
  
  room: {                         // Зачем так делать? Что это?
    number: 23,
    participants: ["john", "ann"]
  }                               // Зачем так делать? Что это?

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша переменная `meetup` ссылается на объект (содержит объект). Так же и ключи объекта могут ссылаться на объекты.

Используется повсеместно для очень многих вещей. Например чтобы передать вложенные данные типа этих:

```
let settings = {
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 10,
    },
    size: {
        width: 20,
        height: 30,
    }
}
```

Comment: size{} это объект в объекте settings?

Comment: Грубо говоря да. Но если точнее, то `size` - это ключ, ссылающийся на другой объект.

Comment: Size ссылается на объект size, который содержит два свойства width и height внутри родительского объекта settings?

Comment: @Человек родительских объектов не бывает. В JS все объекты отдельные. И только ключ какого-то объекта может ссылаться на другой объект. То, что они друг в друге написаны - это просто для визуального удобства. Это не означает что один родительский, а другой дочерний. Оба этих объекта абсолютно самостоятельны. Никогда ни у какого объекта нет вложенности. Есть только ключи, которые могут ссылаться на другой объект, и поэтому создаётся впечатление вложенности, и часто просто думают так для удобства.

Answer (score 0):

`meetup` это объект, у которого два свойства: `title` и `room`.

На примере поля `title: "Conference"`, здесь `title` это ключ, который может быть только строкой, а вот значение может быть каким угодно типом данных, в даннном случае тоже строка: `"Conference"`.

Что касается второго свойства:

```
room: {                         
  number: 23,
  participants: ["john", "ann"]
}
```

здесь значением является объект, который также содержит два свойства, и второй из них еще содержит массив.

По поводу того зачем это нужно, в первую очередь для того чтобы удобно организовать структуру данных, если с практической стороны посмотреть, то в подобном виде данные могут прилетать с сервера.

Comment: room{} это объект, который хранит в себе два свойства в родительском объекте meetup? 
Грубо говоря room это объект в объекте meetup?

Comment: да, грубо говоря это так, `meetup` это объект внутри которого есть объект `room`

Comment: А если не грубо говоря, то как будет правильно?